# Hyperref does not work for List of Fig/Tables and previous textblocks (Abstract etc.)

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

The final PDF does not have the links for the Acknowledgement, Abstract, Kurzfassung, List of Tables and Figures.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tocloft} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section*{Acknowledgement}
\section*{Abstract}
\section*{Zusammenfassung}

\clearpage

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}{Acknowledgement}}
\listoffigures
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}{Abstract}}
\listoftables
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}{Zusammenfassung}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}{Table of Contents}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}{List of Figures}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}{List of Tables}}
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

THIS IS TEXT OF ZUSAMMEFASSUNG: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur 

\clearpage

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}{Acknowledgement}}
\listoffigures
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}{Abstract}}
\listoftables
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}{Zusammenfassung}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}{Table of Contents}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}{List of Figures}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}{List of Tables}}
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}


\section{Introduction}
TEXT INTRO: Lorem ipsum dolo



\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the duplicating `\addcontentsline` entries, which are also on the wrong locations?

Answer (score 2):

The doubling of the `\addcontentsline` is useless and they are at the wrong position, as Heiko Oberdiek already noted in his comment.

I my opinion, the `\numberline` is wrongly used and there should be `\clearpage` after the sections.

The entries of `toc` etc. to the `ToC` itself can be optained with `tocbibind` package out of the box.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
%\usepackage{tocloft} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgement}
\section*{Acknowledgement}
\blindtext[5]
\clearpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}
\section*{Abstract}
\clearpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Zusammenfassung}
\section*{Zusammenfassung}

\clearpage

\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\listoftables
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

THIS IS TEXT OF ZUSAMMEFASSUNG: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur 


\pagenumbering{arabic}


\section{Introduction}
TEXT INTRO: Lorem ipsum dolo

\begin{figure}
  \caption[Dummy figure]{Dummy figure content}
\end{figure}


\begin{table}
  \caption[Dummy table]{Dummy table content}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have had to delete: %\setlength\cftparskip{2pt}
%\setlength\cftbeforesecskip{1pt}
%\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{2pt}
%\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

Comment: Yes of course, because you did not specifiy you would need them at all -- those commands do not appear in your 'MWE'